# Fastest way to converge to mean

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, central-limit-theorem

Given a sequence of i.i.d random variables $\{X_k\}_{k=1}^N$, from the central limit theorem, we know that
$$
\left(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^N X_k \right)- \mathbb{E}(X_1) = \mathcal{o}_p\left(1\right)
$$
Is there any way to obtain an estimator for mean with a faster rate of convergence in probability?

Comment: I see, so now I removed my downvote.

Comment: For finite variance the mean square error for estimator $M_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ is $E[(M_n-m)^2] = \frac{\sigma^2}{n}$ so we can ask if we can do better than $O(1/n)$.  But a lucky estimator can guess $m$ exactly! So a more precise version of the problem fixes a family of distributions and shows that any measurable estimator must have values of $m \in \mathbb{R}$ for which the estimator performs poorly.  See Cramer-Rao bound and also Theorems 1 and 2 here: http://viterbi-web.usc.edu/~mjneely/docs/neely-converse-network-utility-TON.pdf

Comment: The short answer from Theorems 1-2 is that for estimating $p$ from i.i.d. Bernoulli($p$) samples $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ then no estimator can do better than $\Theta(1/n)$: For any measurable estimator that relies on the first $n$ samples, the set of values of $p \in [0,1]$ over which the estimator performs poorly has positive Lebesgue measure in $[0,1]$ (its measure is at least $1/6$).

Answer (score 4):

If $X_1$ has a finite variance, then the [law of the iterated logarithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_iterated_logarithm) states that the random variable
$$
M=\sup_{n\geqslant 3}\frac 1{\sqrt{n \log \log n}}\left\lvert \sum_{k=1}^n(X_k-\mathbb E(X_k))\right\rvert
$$is almost surely finite. Therefore,
$$
\left\lvert\frac 1N\sum_{k=1}^NX_k-\mathbb E(X_1)\right\rvert=\frac 1N
\left\lvert\sum_{k=1}^N(X_k-E[X_k])\right\rvert\leqslant \frac{\sqrt{\log \log N}}{\sqrt N}M.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Is there any estimator which is even faster? Possibly at an exponential rate in $N$? Or is it impossible to construct such?

Comment: Actually, we do not even have $o_{\mathbb P}(\sqrt{\log \log N}/\sqrt N)$ precisely because of the law of the iterated logarithms.

Comment: @user808843 It seems like you are searching for Cramer’s theorem or something similar. You have some exponential convergence (though in a different sense than you describe) as long as you have exponential moments.